# Swift | I'm trying to rotate a sprite and change the direction of the rotation ever time I tap

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to rotate a single sprite indefinitely, and every time I tap the button, I want the sprite to rotate in the opposite direction (back and forth from clockwise to counter-clockwise etc.

Below is the code that I have:

http://pastebin.com/Avj8Njwt

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var center = SKSpriteNode()
    var bg = SKSpriteNode()
    var bigCircle = SKSpriteNode()
    let counterClockwise = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(3.14), duration:1)
    let clockwise = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-3.14), duration:1)
    var spin = SKAction()


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

//Background
        var bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "images/bg.png")
        bg = SKSpriteNode(texture:bgTexture)
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(center)

//Center Circle
        var bigCircleTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "images/bigCircle.png")
        bigCircle = SKSpriteNode(texture:bigCircleTexture)
        bigCircle.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(bigCircle)

//Center Triangle
        var centerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "images/center.png")
        center = SKSpriteNode(texture:centerTexture)
        center.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(center)
        spin = clockwise
        center.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spin))
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        if spin == clockwise  {
            spin = counterClockwise

        }

        else {
            spin  = clockwise
        }
        center.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spin))
}


    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using sprite kit? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to poste my current code. Up now.

Comment: Is the issue that the action you set in didMoveToView is never stopping?

Comment: Well I do want it to spin forever...until the button is pressed of course. Then I want it to change direction and spin forever, again until the button is pressed. Would it help to stop the action in didMoveToView as the button is pressed? It wouldn't matter because  I don't need it after the first press because it's ran in touchesBegan as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're not removing the old `SKAction` trying to rotate your `SKSpriteNode`. To do that you need to keep track of which way your sprite is rotating. If I was going to implement this I would subclass `SKSpriteNode`, like so:

```
class RotatingSprite: SKSpriteNode {
    // This is used to keep track of which way the sprite is rotating.
    enum Direction {
        case Left, Right

        mutating func inverse() {
            switch self {
                case .Left : self = .Right
                case .Right: self = .Left
            }
        }
    }

    // These names will be the keys used when running an action.
    // This will allow you to stop the rotate-left or rotate-right actions.
    static let rotateLeftName  = "RotateLeftAction"
    static let rotateRightName = "RotateRightAction"

    var rotationDirection: Direction? {
        didSet {
            if let r = rotationDirection {
                switch r {
                    // Checks the sprite isn't already rotating to the left.
                    // If it isn't, make the sprite rotate to the left.
                    case .Left where oldValue != .Left:
                        rotateLeft()
                    case .Right where oldValue != .Right:
                        rotateRight()
                    default:
                        break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func rotateLeft() {
        // Remove the action rotating the sprite to the right.
        self.removeActionForKey(RotatingSprite.rotateRightName)
        // And start the action rotating the sprite to the left.
        let rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 1.0)
        self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateAction), withKey: RotatingSprite.rotateLeftName)
    }

    private func rotateRight() {
        self.removeActionForKey(RotatingSprite.rotateLeftName)
        let rotateAction = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 1.0)
        self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateAction), withKey: RotatingSprite.rotateRightName)
    }
}
```

Now you can use `RotatingSprite` like so:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let rotatingSprite = RotatingSprite(texture:bgTexture)

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        rotatingSprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        self.addChild(rotatingSprite)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        // If the sprite isn't turning you've got to set it off.
        if rotatingSprite.rotationDirection == nil {
            rotatingSprite.rotationDirection = .Left

        // If it is turning, change its direction.
        } else {
            rotatingSprite.rotationDirection!.inverse()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, this is a lot more complex than what I thought it would be. I read through your code and understand most of it. I want to see how it works but for some reason I get an error saying static properties are only allowed in structs and enums, and it tells me to put it in a class property. It looks like it's already in a class though.

Comment: Ahh, okay, your problem is you're using an older version of Xcode, try updating to Xcode 6.3 and changing `NSSet` to `Set<NSObject>` and everything should work. Yeah, it gets more complicated, but that's all in the class; this way keeps the scene nice and tidy.

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely easy to achieve this. Try this ,

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

    [sprite removeAllActions];

     SKAction *action;
    if (isClockWise)
    {

        action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1];
    }
    else
    {
        action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:-M_PI duration:1];
    }

   isClockWise = !isClockWise;
    [sprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];

}
```

Where sprite is SKSpriteNode and initiate isClockWise to Yes or No depending on your initial movement direction.

Comment: That will work but it's important to mention that if your sprite is performing any other actions, touching the screen will stop them too.

Comment: I tried the above solution and I'm getting an "Expected Declaration" error pointing at the ' - ' next to (void)

Comment: @ ABakerSmith in the code provided in question there is no other actions performed over sprite.

Comment: @ StudioSevenDesigns  Include this in your interface file `BOOL isClockWise; ` and in `didMoveToView` include this `isClockWise = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to do this is the following:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var center = SKSpriteNode()
    var bg = SKSpriteNode()
    var bigCircle = SKSpriteNode()
    let counterClockwise = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(3.14), duration:1)
    let clockwise = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-3.14), duration:1)
    var spin = SKAction()

    // this is used to identify which direction we are going in. When we change it spin is changed as well
    var isClockwise: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if isClockwise {
                spin = clockwise
            } else {
                spin = counterClockwise
            }
        }
    }

    let actionKey = "spin" // this is used to identify the SKAction

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //Background
        var bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "images/bg.png")
        bg = SKSpriteNode(texture:bgTexture)
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(center)

        //Center Circle
        var bigCircleTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "images/bigCircle.png")
        bigCircle = SKSpriteNode(texture:bigCircleTexture)
        bigCircle.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(bigCircle)

        //Center Triangle
        var centerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "images/center.png")
        center = SKSpriteNode(texture:centerTexture)
        center.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(center)
        isClockwise = true // set the initial direction to clockwise
        center.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spin), withKey: actionKey)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        // remove the existing spin action
        center.removeActionForKey(actionKey)

        // reset the direction (this will automatically switch the SKAction)
        isClockwise = !isClockwise

        center.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spin), withKey: actionKey)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

You need to remove the action before you apply a new one - you can selectively remove the action by calling runAction(action:,withKey:). This enables you to be able to remove that same action using the same key. The logic for changing `spin` is in `didSet` for the `isClockwise` var declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as placing center.removeAllActions in each if statement to make sure the sprite isn't currently moving when the direction is supposed to be changed.